# XAML: Refer to StaticResource in plain XAML? (without markup extension)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, xaml, validation

I am setting a validation rule on a series of textboxes. I'd rather not create a new instance of my custom validation rule for each TextBox...

```
<Window.Resources>
  <my:IsIntegerRule x:Key="IsIntegerRule"/>
</Window.Resources>

...
...

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding XPath="@num" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>

            <-- WHAT IS THE EQUIVALENT OF WRITING: {StaticResource IsIntegerRule} here -->

         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the normal property element syntax for markup extensions.  See [Markup Extensions and WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx).  It looks like this:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="IsIntegerRule"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

Comment: Thanks @Quartermeister, once I placed this in my code I got an error saying **Invalid type** in XAML editor. However it work like charm.