# Does System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule only support Value Types for properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validationrules, validationrule

I am using following System.Windows.ValidationRule.

```
public class XXXValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public object FooObject { get; set;}
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Bar barObject = this.FooObject.BarObject;
    }
}
```

My XAML shows like this.

```
<ui:Windows.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <viewModel:XXXValidationRule x:key="xxxValidationRule"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ui:Windows.Resources>
...
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="..." UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>                   
            <viewModel:XXXValidationRule/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

So far so good. Now in the Code Behind of my XAML Dialog I initialize the ValidationRule as follow.

```
public partial class XamlDialog : System.Windows.Window
{
    private System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule xxxValidationRule;

    public XamlDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeResources();
    }

    public void InitializeResources()
    {
       this.xxxValidationRule = (ValidationRule)this.Resources["xxxValidationRule"];
       this.xxxValidationRule.FooObject= new FooObject();
    }
    ...
 }
```

The point is, when XXXValidationRule.Validate is triggered the FooObject Property is always null.

If I work with the value type int for the Property FooObject, same effect.

If I work still with the value type int and set the Property explicitly in XAML like follow, I receive the correct value (99) within the Validation Rule.

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <viewModel:XXXValidationRule FooObject="99"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
...
```

First, does ValidationRule only supports value types or is there a way to work with reference types as described above? Second, do we have to set such Properties explicitly in XAML or is there a way to set it in Code Behind?

Thanks for help :-)

Comment: your binding `Binding.ValidationRules` will create new instance of `XXXValidationRule` and not use the resource instance where you set `FooObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution. Thanks to the comment of dkozl and this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173461/3835909

If we define the Validation Rule such as

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <viewModel:XXXValidationRule FooObject="99"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
...
```

means that the Binding `Binding.ValidationRules` will create always new instance of `XXXValidationRule`. To resolve that use `StaticResource` as follow.

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="xxxValidationRule"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
...
```